# Usecases for mapred.job.queue.name

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform

What are the real world use cases on using map reduce job queues i.e. the value of `mapred.job.queue.name` property. I see `default` being used as the value always.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

mapred.job.queue.name is what you use to assign a job to a particular queue. By default all jobs go to "default" queue. However, it is possible to create hierarchical queue. Like root, root.q1, root.q1.q1a and so on.
Each of these queues can have its own set of attributes to ensure certain priority.

A real world scenario will be when you have multiple stakeholder asking for reports on same set of infrastructure. For example, at my work place , we have the data scientist trying to run various kind of research job, the customer support team looking for various daily and weekly figures and then there are real jobs that supports the day to day business. It is at the heart that the infrastructure should be able to support the best it can. 
Having various queues with different priorities just makes it easy for Hadoop to decide what to do next when a processor is available, or how much it can use.

So data scientist will assign to "Data Analyst" queue, marketing team will assign to "Marketing" queue. It is possible to change priority of a queue depending on time of the day.

Comment: +1 So i See "Prioritizing" being one of the use-cases. Are there more?

Comment: Other than priority, it also defines the order of execution. So if you have two jobs in a queue. Until Job1 is done or nothing is there in Job1 that can use the available processor, that Job2  kicks in.

Comment: Do you have any insights on controlling security through queue? http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/mapred-default.html

Comment: Only security aspect I can see is , you can configure in such a way, that jobs from user A will always go to QueueA and jobs from user B will always go to QueueB....if you want to consider that as any level of security. Also, it is possible that User A can access only QueueA...

Answer (score 0):

The Map/Reduce system always supports atleast one queue with the name as default. Hence, this parameter's value should always contain the string default. Some job schedulers supported in Hadoop, like the Capacity Scheduler, support multiple queues. If such a scheduler is being used, the list of configured queue names must be specified here. Once queues are defined, users can submit jobs to a queue using the property name mapred.job.queue.name in the job configuration. There could be a separate configuration file for configuring properties of these queues that is managed by the scheduler. Refer to the documentation of the scheduler for information on the same.

Ref: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.19.1/cluster_setup.html